# How to get all datasets associated with a workspace in Power BI

Tags: powershell, api, powerbi

I want all Datasets in a specific workspaceId and right now I'm using,

```
Login-PowerBI 
Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId <workspaceId>
```

But when I use it, it produces error,

```
get-powerbidataset : Login first with Login-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

Comment: Which product you are using Report server or PowerBIserviecs ?

Comment: Follow this issue for more information [Get-PowerBIWorkspace returned "Login first with Login-PowerBIServiceAccount" #183](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/issues/183)